# isa pointer in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios

From this reference:

> When a new object is created, memory for it is allocated, and its
>   instance variables are initialized. First among the object’s variables
>   is a pointer to its class structure. This pointer, called isa, gives
>   the object access to its class and, through the class, to all the
>   classes it inherits from.

From what I could understand reading [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/ObjCRuntimeGuide.pdf) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/ObjC.pdf), it allows, for one, to use introspection but in a pragmatic way (iOS development), **what can a programmer benefit from knowing/understanding this special pointer?**

Comment: read it as "is a". "myObj is a MyClass instance"

Comment: do you have example, that what is a isa pointer please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The real benefit is a better understanding of the Objective-C runtime, which is actually quite complex compared to static languages like C++. The `isa` pointer, in practical terms, isn't really used all that much unless you're hacking the runtime to do something special. [This guide](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html) has more info on how it is used by the runtime.

You shouldn't really use the `isa` directly in production code. It's like `retainCount` - it's important you understand it but you shouldn't ever call it.

Comment: +1 for the guide. Like many people who dedicate some time to stackoverflow, I like to know `how deep the rabbit hole goes`.

Comment: The Objective-C runtime is very much like that! No matter how much you learn, there's probably something else, even if it's a nuanced behaviour or practice.

Answer (score 7):

On 64-bit environment, an object’s `isa` field shouldn’t be accessed. The `isa` field no longer holds a pointer. It includes some pointer data and uses the remaining bits to hold other runtime information. `class` property or `object_getClass()` function can be used to read an `isa` field. `object_setClass()` can be used to write an `isa` field. By the way, if `isa` is set, `[obj class]` might be different with `object_getClass()` such as [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) observed object.

Ref:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/updating_your_app_from_32-bit_to_64-bit_architecture

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

At runtime, when a message is sent to an object, that object goes to the class that created it and says: "I was sent this message. Run the code of the matching method." This is different than most compile language, where the method to be executed is determined at compile time.

---

HOW DOES AN OBJECT KNOW WHICH CLASS CREATED IT?

It uses its **isa** pointer. Every object has an instance variable called isa. When an object is created, the class sets the isa instance variable of the return object to point back at that class. It is called the isa pointer because an object "is a" instance of that class. Although you probably will never explicitly use the isa pointer, it existence gives Objective-C gets much of its power.

---

An object only responds to a message if its class (pointed to by its isa pointer) implements the associated method. Because this happens at runtime, XCode cannot always figure out at compile time (when the application is built) whether an object will respond to a message. XCode will give you an error if it thinks you are sending message to an object that will not respond, but if it is not sure, it will let the application build.

---

If, for some reason (and there are many possibilities), you end up sending a message to an object that does not respond, your application will thrown an exception.
So the **isa** pointer is the reason for *runtime error* . Let's check detail and example here: [IOS - Objective-C - Exceptions And Unrecognized Selectors](http://technicaltut.blogspot.com/2016/01/ios-objective-c-exceptions-and-unrecognized-selectors.html)

Answer (score 3):

isa points to the class object so this would work

```
if(self->isa == [self class])
    NSLog(@"True");
```

Understanding how to use this, would have some benefits, such as introspection and tests on the class objects of the created object

Comment: I would not recommend using this; `if ([self isKindOfClass:[self class]])` is a much better approach, even if checking pointer equality of `Class` objects is technically correct.

Comment: @AshFurrow what do you think `isKindOfClass:` uses to implement its behaviour...? ;)

Comment: Of course! But that's under the hood. Just like you shouldn't call `.cxx_destruct` or `objc_msgSend` yourself.

Comment: there might be situations, where `isKindOfClass:` will fail: If an object neither is a subclass of NSObject nor implements the NSObject protocol.

Comment: That's a pedantic difference. If an Objective-C object doesn't extend one of the root classes (`NSProxy` or `NSObject`), then you'd have to write your own `isa` pointer, but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: The base classes don't implement the isa pointer— it's part of `struct objc_object`. But the idiomatically correct way to 'use' it is via calling the ObjC runtime APIs directly, as with `object_getClass()` or `class_getSuperclass()`. These look at the `isa` pointer internally, but the NSObject methods all call through to these. Only the ObjC runtime implementation should work with these.

Comment: The correct way to implement the sample above would be to use `[self isMemberOfClass: someClass]`. This is like `isKindOfClass:` except it doesn't check the hierarchy, only the actual receiver's class.

Comment: Direct access of the isa will crash on Lion with certain classes whose instances are implemented as tagged pointers.

Comment: This should not be used in production code because of all the reasons mentioned above.