# Objective-C: use isa property to determine if variable has been deallocated

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a problem where a variable is randomly deallocated or corrupted and I get an NSInvalidArgumentException. It doesn't always happen but I'm able to reproduce the problem after a few tries.

I've tried a few ways to check if the property is the right type but with no success.

Here is the variable when everything is working
[image: Here is the variable when everything is working]

Here is the variable when the app crashes
[image: Here is the variable when the app crashes]

I've noticed that the "**isa** = (Class)" part now returns an error instead of "CLLocation" so I'm trying to check it but it's protected.

```
[fromPoint->isa isKindOfClass:[CLLocation class]]
```

I've tried the answers here but I'm still getting the exception.

[Objective c isKindOfClass missunderstanding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045561/objective-c-iskindofclass-missunderstanding)

[isa pointer in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998984/isa-pointer-in-objective-c)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks you have references to deallocated objects. Try to run the debugger with `NSZombieEnabled=YES`. Set this by opening *Product>Edit Scheme...* and adding a row to the "Environment Variables" of the Run configuration.

Comment: Also turn on some options under **Diagostics > Memory Management** in your debugging Scheme to track down potential memory issues.

Comment: What Krumelur said; the crash is a symptom and your attempt to validate the isa is an attempt to address the symptom.  Doing so won't fix the actual bug.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I think the bug is that `fromPoint` was being set to a pointer reference: 

`fromPoint = locationController.currentLocation;` 

I've changed it to this: 

`fromPoint = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:locationController.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationController.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];`

I'm thinking that `locationController.currentLocation` was getting deallocated causing the bug.